# Sharepoint 2010 Auto update twitter status

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, publishing

We have a SharePoint 2010 installation branded for use as our corporate website.  I am creating a "News" section using SharePoint Publishing features and I have been requested by the powers that be to find a way to integrate new news articles into the corporate twitter feed.  What they want is when they create a new article (by creating a new page in the publishing site) and then save and 'Publish' the article, they want it to auto update the corporate twitter feed with the title of the article.

It sounds like there needs to be a way to intercept the publish process and grab the data, then do an update to the twitter API.   Has anyone ever done this or is this even possible?

Comment: BradL,
Did you ever get this working? I need to do something similar so would be keen to hear how you got on with this.
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An event receiver could accomplish this. However, I would recommend a custom task in a workflow or a timer job or an external process. Using the w3wp.exe process (which is what the event receiver uses) to execute a web request has the risk of impacting page response time.

Also, last time I looked, Twitter had some stringent requirements about an application using their API on behalf of users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Great idea on the workflow.  I hadn't thought of that.